# Fraction operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

30 tennis balls are used by 9 tennis ball players in 2 days, how many tennis balls are used by 11 tennis ball players in 3 days?

I've tried 
2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 = 15 for 9 players a day
Which means I'll get 17 for 11 players, but it'll be 51
The answer is not on the list though, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come on, this is pretty easy! Let's assume that one player uses a constant amount of balls in a constant time. If 9 players use 30 balls in 2 days, it means that one player uses
$$
\frac{30}{9\times 2} = \frac{5}{3}
$$
per one day. Then 11 players would use $\frac{5}{3}\times 11 \times 3 = 55$ tennis balls in three days.